# Can't click on a button with startDrag() active on stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I need to know how can I enable mouse click on a button when I have a `MouseEvent` listener for the stage.

I have an `MClip` associated with the mouse cursor:

```
Mouse.hide();
scope.startDrag(true);
```

And a `MouseEvent` on the stage:

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, FunctionXYZ);
```

When I try to click on any button they don't call the function that I create for those buttons... for example, button for fullscreen, exit, help, etc... What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can try:

```
MClip.mouseEnabled = false
```